# Can I combine ten similar SQL queries to one?

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my MySQL query:

```
SELECT ROUND(SUM(cfv.NUMBERVALUE),0) AS mysum
FROM jissue ji JOIN customfieldvalue cfv ON ji.ID=cfv.ISSUE
WHERE ji.pkey LIKE '%PB-%' 
AND cfv.customfield=11381 AND ji.issuestatus=10127;
```

There are two possible cfv.customfield (11381 and 11382) and five possible ji.issuestatus (10127 -> 10131), so I run the query ten times changing those two fields each time.

Is it possible to compress this into one query that will return all ten SUMs?

**EDIT: I would like the result to also include empty values.** Currently, only 8 rows are returned because ji.issuestatus=10128 has no NUMBERVALUE for 11381 and 11382. I would like the result to also include 10128 with empty values for 11381/2.

Comment: If you want it together, then you can use IN property. If you are looking for a specific combination of cfv.customfield and ji.issuestatus, you can use a combination of OR and IN corresponding to your combinations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. As said wumpz and Anthony Grist, you use `GROUP BY` to return all 2*5 sums *without sums for missing entries*.
2. To return sums for missing entries, you use LEFT JOIN. Difference between `tableexpr1 JOIN tableexpr2 ON ...` and `tableexpr1 LEFT JOIN tableexpr2 ON ...` is with LEFT JOIN entries from tableexpr1 are output even when there are no corresponding entries in tableexpr2.

   ```
   SELECT ji.issuestatus, cf.ID AS customfield_id, ROUND(SUM(cfv.NUMBERVALUE),0) AS mysum
   FROM
       jissue ji CROSS JOIN customfield cf
       LEFT JOIN customfieldvalue cfv ON cfv.ISSUE=ji.ID AND cfv.customfield=cf.ID
   WHERE
       ji.pkey LIKE '%PB-%'
       AND ji.issuestatus IN (10127,10128,10129,10130,10131)
       AND cf.ID IN IN (11381, 11382)
   GROUP BY ji.issuestatus, cf.ID;
   ```

Comment: FULL OUTER JOIN returns a MySQL error.    LEFT JOIN just gives the same result as JOIN.  Here is the SQL I am using now:  SELECT cfv.customfield, ji.issuestatus, ROUND(SUM(cfv.NUMBERVALUE),0) AS mysum
FROM jissue ji LEFT JOIN customfieldvalue cfv ON ji.ID=cfv.ISSUE
WHERE ji.pkey LIKE '%PB-%' 
AND cfv.customfield IN (11381, 11382) AND ji.issuestatus IN (10127, 10128, 10129, 10130, 10176)
GROUP BY cfv.customfield, ji.issuestatus

Comment: Could you please tell which exactly pairs of (cfv.customfield, ji.issuestatus) are present?

Comment: customfield issuestatus mysum  
11381 10127 10  
11381 10129 8000  
11381 10130 100  
11381 10176 99  
11382 10127 2999  
11382 10129 1000  
11382 10130 90000  
11382 10176 200000

Comment: MySQL said: 

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'VALUES (11381), (11382)) cfvcf
    LEFT JOIN customfieldvalue cfv ON cfv.ISSUE=j' at line 4

Comment: So, I guess it is impossible in MySQL.

Comment: Do you have some table like `customfields` (that lists all possible customfield ids)?

Comment: Yes, there is customfield table too:

CREATE TABLE customfield (
  ID decimal(18,0) NOT NULL,
  CUSTOMFIELDTYPEKEY varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  CUSTOMFIELDSEARCHERKEY varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  cfname varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  DESCRIPTION text,
  defaultvalue varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  FIELDTYPE decimal(18,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  PROJECT decimal(18,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  ISSUETYPE varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (ID)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

Comment: Again, it just returns 8 rows and not the 2 empty ones.  issuestatus customfield_id mysum
10127 11381 10
10127 11382 2999
10129 11381 8000
10129 11382 1000
10130 11381 100
10130 11382 90000
10176 11381 99
10176 11382 200000

Comment: Please tell me which pairs of (cfv.customfield, ji.issuestatus) are "empy ones".

Comment: Are there issues with `issuestatus`=`10128` in `jissue` table?

Comment: Is there table like `issuestatuses` (that lists all possible issuestatus values)?

Comment: ji.issuestatus=10128 has no csv.NUMBERVALUE for csv.customfield 11381 and 11382.

Comment: There are no issues with issuestatus=10128 in jissue table.  Maybe this is key to the problem?

Comment: Yes, there is issuestatus table:  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `issuestatus` (
  `ID` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `SEQUENCE` decimal(18,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pname` varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DESCRIPTION` text,
  `ICONURL` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
)

Comment: "There are no issues with issuestatus=10128 in jissue table. Maybe this is key to the problem?" Yes

Comment: The SQL has 10128 in it, so it would be good if it returned NULL for that row.  But it doesn't.  So I give up on this, I will just use the ten queries and put up with the extra load.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
SELECT cfv.customfield, ji.issuestatus, ROUND(SUM(cfv.NUMBERVALUE),0) AS mysum
FROM jissue ji JOIN customfieldvalue cfv ON ji.ID=cfv.ISSUE
WHERE ji.pkey LIKE '%PB-%' 
AND cfv.customfield IN (11381, 11382) AND ji.issuestatus IN (10127, 10128, ..., 10131)
GROUP BY cfv.customfield, ji.issuestatus
```

The first two columns and the GROUP BY clause are there so that you have a sum for each of the ten different combinations, otherwise you're just going to have the sum of all rows that match any of the ten combinations.

Comment: This works, however I would like it to also return empty values.  Currently, ji.issuestatus=10128 has no NUMBERVALUE for 11381 and 11382.  I would like the result to also include 10128 with empty values for 11381/2.

Answer (score 1):

Sum is an aggregate function. It aggregates values from the groups you are defining using **group by**. So I don't know MySQL syntax very well, but this would be my first guess.

```
SELECT ROUND(SUM(cfv.NUMBERVALUE),0) AS mysum,
cfv.customfield,ji.issuestatus
FROM jissue ji JOIN customfieldvalue cfv ON ji.ID=cfv.ISSUE
WHERE ji.pkey LIKE '%PB-%' 
AND cfv.customfield in (11381,11382) AND ji.issuestatus in (10127, ... , 10131)
group by cfv.customfield,ji.issuestatus
```

Answer (score 0):

yes you can use My sql IN function.

Try this

```
SELECT ROUND(SUM(cfv.NUMBERVALUE),0) AS mysum
FROM jissue ji JOIN customfieldvalue cfv ON ji.ID=cfv.ISSUE
WHERE ji.pkey LIKE '%PB-%' 
AND cfv.customfield IN(11381,11381) AND ji.issuestatus IN (10127,10128,10129,10130,10131)    GROUP BY cfv.customfield, ji.issuestatus;
```

Comment: The OP wants ten sums instead of one, so I guess you're missing a GROUP BY here.